# Shuffling structured array (Record arrays)

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, structured-array

How can I shuffle structured array. `numpy.random.shuffle` does not seem to work. Further is it possible to shuffle only a given field say `x` in the following example.

```
import numpy as np
data = [(1, 2), (3, 4.1), (13, 77), (5, 10), (11, 30)]
dtype = [('x', float), ('y', float)]
data1=np.array(data, dtype=dtype)
data1
>>> array([(1.0, 2.0), (3.0, 4.1), (13.0, 77.0), (5.0, 10.0), (11.0, 30.0)], 
      dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8')])

np.random.seed(10)
np.random.shuffle(data)
data
>>> [(13, 77), (5, 10), (1, 2), (11, 30), (3, 4.1)]
np.random.shuffle(data1)
data1
>>> array([(1.0, 2.0), (3.0, 4.1), (1.0, 2.0), (3.0, 4.1), (1.0, 2.0)], 
      dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8')])
```

I understand that I can explicitly give the randomized index,

```
data1[np.random.permutation(data1.shape[0])]
```

but I want a in place shuffling.

Comment: It might be this numpy bug: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/4270

Comment: @Warren, you are right. Fixed in numpy 1.8.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to a numpy bug https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/4270
In `Numpy 1.8.1` this has been resolved. Now it work as expected.

```
np.random.shuffle(data1)
data1
>>> array([(1.0, 2.0), (13.0, 77.0), (11.0, 30.0), (5.0, 10.0), (3.0, 4.1)], 
      dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8')])
```

Answer (score 0):

`numpy.random.shuffle` seemes to support multi-dimentional array.
See [doc here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html). The example on the doc indicates you can pass multi-dimentional array as a parameter.

So I don't know why your code doesn't work.

But there is another approach to do it. Like:

```
shuffledIndex = random.shuffle(xrange(len(data)))
shuffledData = data[shuffledIndex]
```

oops...

```
import random
shuffledIndex = random.sample(xrange(len(data1)), len(data1))
shuffledData = data1[shuffledIndex]
```

Comment: Thanks. I am also puzzled why it does not work. I understand that I can explicitly give the randomized index.

Comment: `data1` is a 1-d array (structured) array, so I don't think the multidimensional support is relevant.